# update routing not working in node with ejs templating (404 not found error)

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, routes, ejs

editUser.js which is loading the data correctly, however when clicking on update I am getting (404 not found error), not able to understand why update route is not getting invoked. It is working for /, createUser, editUser/:id (for loading user data).

editUser.js

```
<div class="container">
  <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">All Users</a>
  <form class="col g-3 mt-3"" method="post" action="/update/<%= user.id %>">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="inputFirstName" class="form-label">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<%= user.first_name %>" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="inputLastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value=<%= user.last_name%> name="last_name" id="last_name">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="form-label">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" value=<%= user.email%> name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </div>
  </form>
 </div>
```

routes/index.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


var {allUsers, createUser, saveUser, editUser, updateUser} = require('../controllers/userController')

/* GET users listing. */
//Commenting default function
router.get('/', allUsers)
router.get('/createUser', createUser)
router.post('/createUser', saveUser)
router.get('/editUser/:id', editUser)
router.post('/updateUser/:id', updateUser)

module.exports = router;
```

controllers/userController.js

```
const User = require('../models/userModel')

const updateUser = async (req, res) => {
console.log('Updating User')

const userId = req.params.id
const userData = req.body
const selector = {where: {id:userId}}

await User.update(userData, selector).catch(error => console.log(error))

res.redirect('/')
}

module.exports = {  allUsers,createUser,saveUser,editUser,updateUser }
```

app.js

```
    //Imports
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')

const routes = require('./routes');

//DOTENV  for storing sensitive data
require('dotenv').config({path:'./bin/.env'})

var app = express();

// View engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); //Key, Value

app.set('layout','layouts/layout')

//Middleware between requet and response
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(expressLayouts)

//Use Router
app.use('/',routes)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
//error handler first parameter is "err"
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form action should be `action="/updateUser/<%= user.id %>`

Comment: Thanks Aimsat its working now, this is what happens when you work beyond capacity... my silly mistake :).